# How to set personalized legends for each variable in a seaborn pairplot?

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm using this code

```
sns.set(palette="dark")

g=sns.pairplot(PCA_atrF_df, x_vars={'CP1','CP3','ModCP2'}, hue= 'Hemis',
               y_vars={'Media','SD','DesMax', 'DesMin' })

def corrfunc(x, y, **kws):
    r, _ = stats.pearsonr(x, y)
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.annotate("r = {:.2f}".format(r),
                xy=(.65, .03), xycoords=ax.transAxes)

g.map(corrfunc)      
sns.plt.show()
```

`x` and `y` vars are columns of a dataframe (`PCA_atrF_df`). I also have two categories ("Hemis": Sur or Norte), and I incoporate r2 (pearson) to get this plot:

[image]

But I need to set `x` legends personalized as:

```
'CP1: 0.71'   'ModCP2: 0.17'   'CP3: 0.05'
```

The numbers come from the first 3 positions of this array:

```
array([ 0.71147788,  0.17629621,  0.05131766,  0.02616651,  0.01864328,
        0.00529765,  0.0043043 ,  0.00197723,  0.00146853,  0.00112802,
        0.0010507 ,  0.00087202])
```

Also, as you can see there are blurry r2 (pearson correlation) in each plots since I'm getting one correlation for each "Hemis". It`s possible to adjust just one r2 for the hole set despite de "Hemis" but conserve the colors of each "hemis"?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the personalized legend using a related question in a not such an elegant way, but at least is working. Just in case anyone need it or can improve it. I´m still looking forward to solve the unique correlation issue (one r2 for two categories).

```
sns.set(palette="dark")

g=sns.pairplot(PCA_atrF_df, x_vars=['CP1','ModCP2','CP3'], hue='Hemis',
               y_vars=['DesMax', 'DesMin','SD','Media'])

def corrfunc(x, y, **kws):
    r, _ = stats.pearsonr(x, y)
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.annotate("r = {:.2f}".format(r),
                xy=(.65, .03), xycoords=ax.transAxes)

g.map(corrfunc)  

xlabels,ylabels = [],[]

for ax in g.axes[-1,:]:
    xlabel = ax.xaxis.get_label_text()
    xlabels.append(xlabel)
for ax in g.axes[:,0]:
    ylabel = ax.yaxis.get_label_text()
    ylabels.append(ylabel)

for i in range(len(xlabels)):

        g.axes[3,i].xaxis.set_label_text(xlabels[i]+ ': '+ str(pca.fracs[i])[:4])


plt.show()
```

[image]

In this case the legend i wanted to add was (the first 3 numbers):

```
array([  6.13922272e-01,   2.94925588e-01,   4.30136304e-02,
         2.94031518e-02,   7.90963090e-03,   4.43885165e-03,
         3.09109701e-03,   1.17998760e-03,   8.80521733e-04,
         5.21848967e-04,   4.39901495e-04,   2.73517962e-04])
```